Equation in space of complex numbers
Giving an equation: $$z^2-(m+2)z+4(m-1)=0$$
I need to find the number of all the integer $m$ such that this equation has two complex solutions $z_1$, $z_2$ that satisfy: $$\vert z_1^2-m(z_1-4)\vert=\vert z_2^2-m(z_2-4)\vert$$
My solution:
First, the equation has two different complex solutions if only if: $$\triangle=b^2-4ac<0$$
In fact: $$(m+2)^2-16(m-1)<0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow m^2-12m+20<0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 2<m<10$$
The second condition:
Because $z_1$, $z_2$ are two solutions of the equation, then:
$$\begin{cases}
z_1^2-m(z_1-4)=2z_1+4\\z_2^2-m(z_2-4)=2z_2+4
\end{cases}$$
So I have: $$\vert z_1+2\vert=\vert z_2+2\vert$$
What does this condition mean ? I need an explanation please.

Real numbers are also complex numbers, so the discriminant doesn't have to be negative. When you are asked for complex solutions it means the solutions can be real or not, it doesn't means that the solutions are necessarily non-real.

First of all, the roots can be $3$ and $5$ (real but not equal) and so you need to consider $D\neq0$ not $D<0$. One way to proceed is:
Since $z_1$ and $z_2$ are roots of the given quadratic, $z_1+2$ and $z_2+2$ are roots of
$$(z-2)^2-(m+2)(z-2)+4(m-1)=0$$
which simplifies to
$$z^2-(m+6)z-(2m-4)=0$$
The roots of this quadratic have equal magnitude. Here, $D=(m+6)^2-4(2m-4)=m^2+4m+52$. Therefore, $|-b+\sqrt{D}|=|-b-\sqrt{D}|$. Now, $D\neq0$ so it must be that
$$-b+\sqrt{D}=b+\sqrt{D}$$
or $m=-6$.
Hope this helps. :)
